# ¿Por qué "la pera que calla es buena"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, comida, refranes

En el Diccionario de Autoridades he encontrado (en el epígrafe "pera") el refrán

> "**La mujer y la pera, la que calla es buena**". Refrán que enseña a las mujeres cuan provechoso y laudable es el silencio.

pero no lo acabo de entender. La parte referente a la mujer que habla poco o no habla es un tópico frecuente (por ejemplo: en [***El médico a palos***](https://es.wikisource.org/wiki/El_m%C3%A9dico_a_palos:_21), de Molière, acto II, escena V, se recoge: "**una mujer que no habla es un tesoro**"), pero ¿por qué "la pera que calla es buena"?

Comment: He buscado en el Covarrubias, en "pera" se cita este mismo dicho, y en "callar" se dice que es buena cualidad para todo el mundo (hombre o mujer), amén de muchas otras cosas, pero nada sobre el dicho. Pensaba que igual "callar" tendría alguna acepción diferente que afectase a las peras, pero nada...

Comment: ¿Es posible que sea un dicho de origen gallego? En gallego, el presente de subjuntivo del verbo "caer" es "caia" (caiga), que se pronunciaría como "calla". Si es así, podría significar que la pera que caiga está madura y por tanto está buena. No se me ocurre otra posible explicación ahora mismo.

Comment: En ["Estereotipos del habla femenina en el refranero Español"](http://www.paremia.org/wp-content/uploads/P16-9.pdf) aparecen también "Mujer y pera, la que no suena, ésa es la buena", "Mujeres y almendras, las que no suenan" y "Mujer y perra, la que calla es buena". No explica el porqué de "pera", a menos que sea una corrupción de "perra", aunque viendo el refrán de la almendra, bien puede ser que sea símplemente una variedad de "la mujer y la XYZ, la que no habla-molesta-opina-piensa es la buena". En el documento vienen montones de ejemplos del refranero censurando a la mujer.

Comment: La pera que no está madura hace ruido al partirla.

Answer (score 12):

En la entrada de "callar" del [Diccionario de la RAE](https://books.google.cl/books?id=ETwiAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA174&lpg=PA174&dq=%22que%20calla%20es%20buena%22&source=bl&ots=gAqYJhi9vS&sig=yuSYIz_mZ5OkwawLqV1O1ZolOZw&hl=es-419&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22que%20calla%20es%20buena%22&f=false) de 1791 se explica: las peras buenas son las que no suenan al partirlas.

> LA MUGER Y LA PERA LA QUE CALLA ES BUENA. ref. que alaba á la muger silenciosa con la semejanza de la pera , que quando es buena , ó madura no mete ruido al partirla. 
>  *Femina , sive pirum , que sit taciturna probatur*.

Answer (score 9):

En el Diccionario de Refranes de [Sbarbi](https://archive.org/details/diccionarioderef02sbaruoft) igualmente se recoge:

> *La mujer y la pera, la que calla es buena,* o *es mamadera*
>   Recomienda el silencio a las mujeres, a la manera que es aceptable la pera
>   que no cruje cuando se come, porque, de hacer ruido en esta ocasión, es señal cierta de ser de mala calidad o de hallarse aún verde, y, por tanto, fuera
>   de sazón para ser comida. Por eso dice otro refrán, que *Pera que dice "Rodrigo", no vale un higo.*